# ffmpeg - получение размеров кадра с точностью до десятых (Запись в бд)

Tags: python, mysql, ffmpeg, decimal

```
ffmpeg -i /var/www/data/www/1.mp4 -ss 5 -t 30 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print  $NF }' | tail -1
```

На выходе получаю

```
crop=640:480:0:50
```

Вопрос в том, возможно ли получить кроп с точностью до сотых или десятых?

Второй порос, в бд полю (width) присвоено DECIMAL(5,2)

При попытке

```
n = 2
SQL.update("UPDATE news set width = '"+str(n)+"' WHERE id = '2'")
```

Ошибка именно в том, что полю присвоено с точностью до сотых.

Как будет верно преобразовать целое число или в целом преобразовать число которое станет возможным записать в поле с данным типом?

Comment: А с какой по вашему точностью вы получили? ```width:height:x:y``` (p.s. это 4 отдельных числа, а не одно дробное число)

Comment: Что ширина, что высота, они не с точностью до сотых, а округленные.

Comment: Компьютерный пиксель штука "неделимая" :) добавьте в конце .00 и будет вам до сотых :)